# Android v3.3.0 variant.getMegrate() is obsolete and replaced with variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, react-native

I have some error to build react-native init app in Android studio by
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

- > Android Version 3.3.0
- > Gradle Version  4.10.1

How solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0IR7.png)

> WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'. It will be removed
>   at the end of 2019. For more information, see
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. REASON:
>   Called from:
>   /home/.../AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle:136
>   WARNING: Debugging obsolete API calls can take time during
>   configuration. It's recommended to not keep it on at all times.
>   Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue,

> Android Version 3.3.0
>     Gradle Version 4.10.1

is not stable i think,

downgrading to my previous settings

> Android Version 3.2.1
>     Gradle Version 4.7

worked for me.
Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed easy open your project folder and goto the following directory

```
node_moduals/react-native
```

Now open the react.gradle file in an editor i use notepad++ my self goto line 147 and replace it with the following

```
dependsOn(variant.getMergeAssetsProvider().get())
```

Then goto line number 96 and replace it with the following

```
? variant.getPackageApplicationProvider().get()
```

and line number 93 replace it with

```
variant.getMergeResourcesProvider().get().dependsOn(currentBundleTask)
```

save the file and now open android studio and sync your gradle and all you warnings should now be gone